# Cmd exist/closes on executing mvn -v

Tags: maven, batch-file, cmd

I am new to maven. I am trying to install maven in my system(windows 10).

In the setup process, i addded the environment variables for M2_HOME and %M2_HOME%\bin.

After that i am trying to check the version for verification i.e mvn -version command.

As soon as i execute the command, the cmd prints all the details and closes the cmd.

I am not sure if the maven is installed correctly or not.

kindly help.

Maven : apache-maven-3.6.3-bin.zip

Downloaded from : https://maven.apache.org/download.cgi

Comment: How do you execute `mvn -version command`? do you type that into a command prompt window or in Windows' Run dialogue?

Comment: I'm going to go wildly speculate here that `mvn` is a batch script so you'd need to use `call mvn -v` instead. Barring that, the other possibility is that `mvn -v` is the last line of the script, so either run the script from the command prompt instead of double-clicking it or just put a `pause` after the last line.

Comment: Based upon your [[tag:batch-file]] tag, I'm assuming that you're running this from a batch file. When a batch file uses `Exit` or has has no more commands left to run, it closes the cmd.exe instance, (Command Prompt window). If you need us to help you with your batch file, please post the its content, by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/61615216/edit) to include it.